# Set segment colors in Pie3 graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, pie-chart

I want change segment colors manually in `Pie3` graph in MATLAB. I'm using this codes :

```
h = pie3([1 2 3],[1 1 1]);
hp = findobj(h, 'Type', 'patch');
set(hp(1), 'FaceColor', 'g');
set(hp(2), 'FaceColor', 'r');
set(hp(3), 'FaceColor', 'b');
```

We have this figure with these codes :
[image]

You can see in 17% segment, We have combination of red and blue. I want `1` in `[1 2 3]` green, `2` red and `3` blue (Respectively). How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
set(h([2 3]), 'FaceColor', 'g');
set(h([6 7]), 'FaceColor', 'r');
set(h([10 11]), 'FaceColor', 'b');
```

You have to modify the "surface" objects, not just the "patch" objects.

Comment: Can you describe more about values you used in your answer? like [2 3] or [6 7]. Thanks.

Comment: I simply noticed that `h` contains 12 objects, and tried setting the `'FaceColor'` property of each object one by one to see the effect